# Sticky footer issue on wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, footer, sticky-footer

I have implemented some CSS for a sticky footer on my a wordpress theme and it seems to be working halfway. You can see the site here: http://westernalaskasportfishing.com/wptest

You'll notice that I'm getting quite a bit too much dead space from the min-height:100%; rule. I'm not the best with sticky footers and I feel like I'm close. Any ideas on how to get this to be fully functional?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with how to help you as I'm wanting to learn this technique myself but I took a look at your site and wow, it's beautiful! I'm new to web design and I would love to get to that level. Do you have any tips?

To all the Stackoverflowers - sorry to interject on this discussion. I just am trying to learn all I can from others and wasn't sure if there was a way to contact users directly thus my reason for posting here.

Answer (score 0):

I not sure what you mean by sticker footer. If by sticky footer you mean you want a element to always stay stuck to the bottom of a webpage, regardless of scrolling, then use CSS "position: fixed; bottom: 0;".

Comment: This method does not work in regards to little amounts of content. I'm looking for a footer that will always be at the bottom, but also with respect to a page with a very small amount of content.

Comment: @MattJones i did the footer `position:fixed;` and `bottom:0;` and it worked for me on your site, via chrome inspector.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't eb at the bottom regardless of content amount. Not unless you have inside a parent element with "position:relative", which in that case just take it outside that parent. It's not going to really matter where it is placed in your file, because it will be stuck t the bottom of the page regardless.